# spring boot not returning an object based on id

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, entity

I am trying to find a particular country by id but I am getting an error when I test it on postman. I am new to spring boot and I have found out that the country id is being represented as a bigint instead of a Long that I have in my Entity class and I don't know if that is the reason that I am getting the error.

Here is my code

```
package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String capital;
    private String description;
    private String nationality;
    private String continent;
}
```

My controller

```
package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.controller;

import com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country;
import com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.services.CountryService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
public class CountryController {
    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    
    @GetMapping("/countries")
    public String getCountry(Model model){
        List<Country> countryList = countryService.getAllCountry();
        model.addAttribute("countries",countryList);

        return "country";
    }
   @PostMapping("/countries/addNew")
    public String saveInfo(Country country){
        countryService.saveCountryInfo(country);
        return "redirect:/countries";
    }
    @GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
    //@ResponseBody
    public Optional<Country> getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Long countryId){ //Bind PathVariable id to id
        return countryService.getCountryById(countryId);
    }
}
```

Service

```
package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.services;

import com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country;

import com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.repository.CountryRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public List<Country> getAllCountry() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }
    public void saveCountryInfo(Country country){
        countryRepository.save(country);
    }
    
    public Optional<Country> getCountryById(Long id){

        return countryRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.repository;

import com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country,Long> {
}
```

And here is the error I got from postman when I pass a certain id to check, note that country with the id 2 exist in my database but I don't know why it's not returning it.Like I said earlier, the country id is stored as bigint in the database instead of Long

```
 "timestamp": "2022-05-22T02:59:30.551+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/findById/2"
```

Here is the error from my stack trace

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [findById/2], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the controller as MVC `@Controller` which needs a view but you returning a object.

Change `@Controller` with `@RestController`
Then problem should be solved.

Comment: But I am returning an html page also, I thought using @RestController will not allow me to return an html page?

Comment: Where did you returning the html/jsp page? And Yes @RestController can't handle views.

Comment: getCountryById this method is not returning any view likely the two other methods.

Comment: This is the error that I am now getting from the logcat while the one in the postman still remains the same. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid Object Id definition for `com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country`: cannot find property with name '@id'

Comment: Using restcontroller also you can return views. This is true and I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to uncomment the `@ResponseBody` annotation

```
@GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Optional<Country> getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Long countryId){ 
  return countryService.getCountryById(countryId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ResponseBody or ResponseEntity

if you use @ResponseBody:

```
@GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Optional<Country> getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Long countryId){ //Bind PathVariable id to id
    return countryService.getCountryById(countryId);
}
```

if you use ResponseEntity:

```
@GetMapping("/findById/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Country> getCountryById(@PathVariable("id") Long countryId){ //Bind PathVariable id to id
    return ResponseEntity.ok(countryService.getCountryById(countryId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue of not getting id in the Response Body of JSON.
And my issue resolved just by adding getter and setter methods in JPA entity.